# Async FTP Upload List of Files

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, ftp, xamarin

I'm trying to loop through a list of images and ftp them to a server. It's partially working except for it is still blocking my UI thread.  Even though my ftp function is async, I'm guessing because my calling method is not, I'm not getting the results I'm looking for. Here's what I got.  What am I doing wrong?

```
   public void UploadPictures()
    {
        //loop through each picture and upload
        for (int i = 0; i < this.items.Count; i++) {

            byte[] bytes;
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension (this.items [i].FileName.ToUpper()) == ".JPG") {
                using (var imageData = this.items[i].Image.AsJPEG())
                {
                    bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
                    Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
                }
                var test=UploadPhoto(bytes,  this.items[i].FileName);

            }

            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension (this.items [i].FileName.ToUpper()) == ".PNG") {
                using (var imageData = this.items[i].Image.AsPNG())
                {
                    bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
                    Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
                }
                var test=UploadPhoto(bytes,  this.items[i].FileName);

            }


        }



    }



    public static async Task<string> UploadPhoto(byte[] photoBytes,  string filename)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://XXXXXXXX/" + filename);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("user", "pass"); 
        request.UseBinary = true;

        request.ContentLength = photoBytes.Length;
        using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            s.Write(photoBytes, 0,photoBytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse ftpResp = await (Task<WebResponse>)request.GetResponseAsync ();

        return ftpResp.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark `UploadPictures` as `async` and `await` on `UploadPhoto`.

Comment: I tried that before and couldn't get it to work right. I can't remember exactly what the issue was. Nonetheless, I used Task Run and that worked(see my post). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I called my UploadPictures function using Task run and that worked. Not sure if thats the most correct way to do it.

```
   Task.Run( () =>
                    {
                        UploadPictures();
            });
```